# Как задать через свойство background размер фона?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть такой css стиль

```
background: url(../img/logo.svg) 100%, url(../img/bg.svg);
```

Два моих фона, должны быть разных размеров, один `cover`, а другой `contain`, как можно это записать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, как пример:

```
html, body {
    background-image: url(../img/logo.svg), url(../img/bg.svg);
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: cover, contain;
}
```